# Add User Emails in WSO2 EMM 1.1.0 not working

Tags: php, email, wso2, jaggery-js, wso2-iot

I am testing WSO2 EMM 1.1.0 on a Ubuntu. When you add a new user an invitation email should go to the user. The email settings can be defined in the configuration page. I have used the followings config for email

```
Host: smtp.gmail.com
Port: 587
Username: email@gmail.com
Password: something
Sender Email Address: email@gmail.com
```

I have used port 587 because in the code tls is mentioned while sending the email. I have tried the same with port 25 also.

```
var sender = new email.Sender(String(emailConfigurations.SMTP[0]), String(emailConfigurations.Port[0]), String(emailConfigurations.UserName[0]), String(emailConfigurations.Password[0]), "tls");
```

Now when I create a user, I get an error saying 'Fatal error occured!'. The moment I delete the Email configs, the error goes away.

The code in ../repository/deployment/server/jaggeryapps/emm/client/js/users/add.js at line#90 defines this error.

```
500: function() {               
  n.setText('Fatal error occured!');    
  n.setType('error');
  n.setTimeout(1000);           
},
```

Any ideas how to resolve this error?